# Average raster data over the specific region in R

Tags: r, raster

I am trying to calculate an average of the parameter over a specific region (long=0:30, lat=40:70).
My data can be found here in .nc format: https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis.dailyavgs/pressure/hgt.2006.nc
What I was trying to do:

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
r_brick <- brick('hgt.2006.nc', "hgt", level = 1)
xy <- cbind(0:30, 40:70)
result <- extract(r_brick, xy, fun=mean)
dfx = data.frame(year = seq(from = 1, to = 365, by = 1), hgt=t(result))
```

As a result, I got 32 columns, but my goal is only one column with an average over the region mentioned above by time. I also tried average over the polygon. But this gives me only one value (average by space and time).

```
cds <- rbind(c(0,40), c(0,70), c(30,70), c(30, 40))
> polys <- spPolygons(cds)
> v <- extract(r_bricks, polys)
> result <- unlist(lapply(v, function(x) if (!is.null(x)) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE) else NA ))
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can either (A) extract and summarize the results, or (B) summarize the raster data and then extract

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
# b has three layers
b
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 77, 101, 7777, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
xy <- cbind(0:30, 40:70)

# approach A
e <- extract(b, xy)
em <- rowMeans(e)
head(em)
#[1] 253.6667 200.6667 172.6667 174.6667 182.0000 195.0000

# approach B
bm <- mean(b)
me <- extract(bm, xy)    
head(me)
#[1] 253.6667 200.6667 172.6667 174.6667 182.0000 195.0000
```

Comment: Thanks, @Robert Hijmans, for trying. Unfortunately, both approaches give me only 31 columns instead of 365. It seems that data were averaged only by lat-long, independently of time.

Comment: Everything is ok :). There should be `em <- colMeans(e)` instead of `em <- rowMeans(e)`. The code works well now. Thank you!